# Split Results of aggregation query and insert into 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, data-structures

I have an aggregation query which totals the number of sales by males and females. The result of print(genderSales) is `[(7,), (14,)]`.

I am trying to insert 7 and 14 into a 2-dimensional array defined as gender. The gender array after being appended to looks like this

```
[['(7,)', '(14,)'], ['(7,)', '(14,)']]
```

Is there a method splitting up the aggregations results so as to display the results in the 2-dimensional array like this:

```
[['(7,)]', ['(14,)']].
```

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("system.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
genderSales = cur.execute("""select COUNT(orderid) as OrderCount
FROM customerOrders
INNER JOIN customerDetails ON
customerDetails.customerid=customerOrders.customerid
GROUP BY customerDetails.gender""").fetchall()

gender = [[],[]]
    for values in genderSales:
        gender[0].append(values)
        gender[1].append(values)
```

Comment: Why are you turning your tuples into strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending all the rows to each element of `gender`. You should just append to one element in each iteration. You can do the whole thing using a list comprehension.

```
gender = [[row] for row in genderSales]
```

BTW, you should have `ORDER BY customerDetails.gender` in the query, so you get the results in a consistent, predictable order.